# How do you add 'box-sizing: border-box' to Normalize.css file?

Tags: css, global, reset, css-reset

I constantly use box-sizing: border-box; on all elements when creating CSS files, ie

```
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However I cannot seem to get this to work with the file 'Normalize.css' (https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css)

I have tried adding the above code to the top of my own CSS file, within normalize itself, but have been unsuccessful

I would very much like to utilise normalize.css as it is not as drastic as some other CSS reset files, but how do I make it accept box-sizing: border-box; so that it effects all elements and is cross browser friendly?

Comment: No reason that should not work. Can you demo?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way I have seen so far of getting box-sizing working is:

```
html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
           -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
                box-sizing: inherit;
    }
```

If your CSS reset (normalize.css) is inserted at the very top of your stylesheet, with this rule just **after normalize**, all should work as expected.

The rule above allows easier control over setting `box-sizing: content-box` for things like third party widgets.

For more information on this technique, I'd recommmend: 
https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ or http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: thanks Andi this format worked perfectly, I'll be using this as a more fool proof method in the future

Answer (score 2):

I created Initialize.css, a collection of best practices like normalize, HTML5 boilerplate and the "box-sizing" trick. It's configurable with SASS or LESS (there's a CSS version as well).  You don't start with CSS overwrites, and that's awesome! :-)

http://jeroenoomsnl.github.io/initialize-css/